# Show a button after a time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi sorry I'm really new to this and I need help.
I'm trying to get a button to appear after say 8 secs.
I want the app to open on a title screen then after 8 secs show a enter button to move on. 
I've set up the screens and everything with the button already there but that's not what I want.
Can someone please help?? I'm using Objective C in Xcode 7.2 and for iPhone ( remember I'm really new lol).
Thanks

Comment: you can use NSTimer for this..

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a Timer approach or a dispatch one, but timer is mostly made for repetition, so I'll go with dispatch :

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 8 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.myButton.hidden = FALSE;
});
```

The first parameter looks weird, but let's explain it with the doc :

> The dispatch_time() function returns a milestone relative to an
>   existing milestone after adding offset nanoseconds.  If the base parameter maps internally to a wall clock, then the returned value is relative to the wall clock.  Otherwise, if base is DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, then the the current time of the default host clock is used.

`NSEC_PER_SEC` represents the number of nanosecond in a second (1000000000), so you just have to multiply it by 8 and got your 8 seconds, that you add to current time represented by `DISPATCH_TIME_NOW`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the steps

1) When viewIs Displayed on the screen you need to set the timer to add button on screen.

2) You detect the view displayed in `ViewWillAppear` in the `ViewController`.

3) In `viewWillAppear` Add the following method with the selector which will be get executed after 10 Sec

```
[self performSelector:@selector(displaybutton:) withObject:request afterDelay:10.0];
```

4) In `displaybutton` method write code to display button Or if you have set image in `StoryBoard` set the button.hidden = No in this method

Answer (score 0):

Set your button property hidden in Interface builder and call this method in your `viewWillAppear`

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:8.0];
}

- (void)showButton{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
                self.startButton.hidden = NO;
            }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                NSLog(@"Done!");
        }];
}
```

Comment: ok shehzad Ali I've done this and its only showing one error:       it says tradeButton is and undeclared identifier

Comment: Its not tradebutton it's reference of your button. Make outlet of yourbutton and use it here

Comment: this what i have now but its not working 8-/                                                [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    startButton.hidden = YES;
    
    
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self showButton];
}
- (void)showButton{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:8.0 animations:^{
       startButton.frame = startButton.frame;
       
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    
  //
    
    startButton.hidden = NO;
   }];
}

Comment: yes, you are having start button. So is it working for you?

Comment: Have you set it hidden in your Interface Builder?

Comment: yes it was hidden before i added the code you provided

Comment: I have updated the code and its working now :) Check it out

Comment: Thank you 8-) I'm out so so I'll try it when I get home. Thanks for all your help

Comment: you are welcome :) Let me know in case you are having any issue :)

Comment: works a treat!! thanks again i really appreciate all your help